# MySQL 5.6 - windows: deleted auto.cnf file accidentally unable to start server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL on windows 8.1 (64 bit). I accidentally deleted file auto.cnf from directory ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data

Now when I am trying to start server getting error

```
E:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqld --init-file=mysql-int1.txt --
console
2014-06-10 01:12:59 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca
ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentati
on for more details).
2014-06-10 01:12:59 5004 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-06-10 01:12:59 5004 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool p
ages
2014-06-10 01:12:59 5004 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-06-10 01:12:59 5004 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlo
cked functions
2014-06-10 01:12:59 5004 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-06-10 01:12:59 5004 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-06-10 01:12:59 5004 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-06-10 01:12:59 5004 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-06-10 01:12:59 5004 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracu
da.
2014-06-10 01:13:00 5004 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-06-10 01:13:00 5004 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-06-10 01:13:00 5004 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 1626
017
error: Found option without preceding group in config file: .\auto.cnf at line:
1
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
2014-06-10 01:13:00 5004 [ERROR] Initialzation of the server's UUID failed becau
se it could not be read from the auto.cnf file. If this is a new server, the ini
tialization failed because it was not possible to generate a new UUID.
2014-06-10 01:13:00 5004 [ERROR] Aborting**
```

Please suggest how can I recover

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1):

As we know that `auto.cnf` stores server uuid.

`auto.cnf` file get generated automatically when server starts up and this may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Since file auto.cnf got deleted accidentally after it was generated first time.  Problem I have is how to regenerate auto.cnf